# Difference between "+" and "-" before function name in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function, syntax

What is the difference between "+" and "-" before the function name interface declaration in an Objective-C program.  Example:

```
- (void)continueSpeaking;

+ (NSArray *)availableVoices;
```

What's the difference?

Comment: And just to be complete: This is not at all iPhone specific, this is Objective-C.

Comment: @user280556 Please accept the answer in order that the question is not  lingering in the 'Unanswered' section.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`+` defines a class method

Class methods belong to the **class** itself, not **instances** of the class.

Example: `[AppDelegate someMethod]`

`-` defines an instance method

Example `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] someMethod]`

One way to describe the difference is that `-` methods operate on objects, while `+` methods operate on the class itself.

Say your class was named `MyClass`, and you created an instance of it and stored it into a variable called `myInstance`:

`- (void)continueSpeaking` can be called like so: `[myInstance continueSpeaking]`.

However, the method `+ (NSArray *)availableVoices` can only be called like so: `[MyClass availableVoices]`

Comment: You're thinking of Java. They are called _class methods_ in Objective-C, and there is a `self` in a class method — `self` is the class. So for example, if your class has the methods `+[MyClass someMethod]` and `+[MyClass someOtherMethod]`, you could call `[self someOtherMethod]` from within `someMethod`.

Comment: Note that the standard `alloc` is a class method that returns an instance, while `init` is an instance method.

Comment: So the + is like calling a function static in languages like c++ or php?