# About "+className" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “+” and “-” before function name in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611419/difference-between-and-before-function-name-in-objective-c)

what does the mean about "+className" in Objective-C?
The +className is a class method name.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In what context? Give an example of where you see it being used.

Comment: You mean a class method?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Comment: I may be wrong but I assume that CocoaUser got confused about the use of *+className...* in the Class Cluster documentation, and the `NSObject` instance method `-className`. In this case this is not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Class Cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) documentation that you are referencing, *+className...* is just a placeholder for the various class methods that are available to create an instance of the class cluster, e.g. `numberWithChar`, `numberWithInt`, ... for `NSNumber`.

This has nothing to do with the `-className` instance method of `NSObject`.

Answer (score -2):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html):

> True Subclasses: An Example
>   Let’s say that you want to create a subclass of `NSArray`, named MonthArray, that returns the name of a month given its index position. However, a MonthArray object won’t actually store the array of month names as an instance variable. Instead, the method that returns a name given an index position (`objectAtIndex:`) will return constant strings. Thus, only twelve string objects will be allocated, no matter how many MonthArray objects exist in an application.
>
> The MonthArray class is declared as:

```
#import <foundation/foundation.h>
@interface MonthArray : NSArray

+ (id)monthArray;
- (unsigned)count;
- (id)objectAtIndex:(unsigned)index;

@end
```

> Note that the MonthArray class doesn’t declare an `init...` method because it has no instance variables to initialize. The `count` and `objectAtIndex:` methods simply cover the inherited primitive methods, as described above.
>
> The implementation of the MonthArray class looks like this:

```
#import "MonthArray.h"

@implementation MonthArray

static MonthArray *sharedMonthArray = nil;
static NSString *months[] = { @"January", @"February", @"March",
    @"April", @"May", @"June", @"July", @"August", @"September",
    @"October", @"November", @"December" };

+ (id)monthArray
{
    if (!sharedMonthArray) {
        sharedMonthArray = [[MonthArray alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMonthArray;
}

- (unsigned)count
{
    return 12;
}

- (id)objectAtIndex:(unsigned)index
{
    if (index >= [self count])
        [NSException raise:NSRangeException format:@"***%s: index
            (%d) beyond bounds (%d)", sel_getName(_cmd), index,
            [self count] - 1];
    else
        return months[index];
 }

@end
```

> Because MonthArray overrides the inherited primitive methods, the derived methods that it inherits will work properly without being overridden. `NSArray`’s `lastObject`, `containsObject:`, `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, `objectEnumerator`, and other methods work without problems for MonthArray objects.

Comment: I cannot see how "+className" relates to category

Comment: Do you mean something like this `+ (ClassName *)Instance`

Comment: NO, take a look --> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Comment: + (SGACommon *)sharedInstance, But your class name not "sharedInstance"

Comment: Yep you are right, I wrote that before you clarified with the link to the documentation. I'm assuming the example in the documentation regarding MonthArray isn't helping you understand?

Comment: Why are you leaving out the return type on some of these methods? The whole _implicitly implied `id`_ compiler feature is just for legacy. Also I'd recommend that this answer be shortened vastly.

Comment: I was just taking the example as per Apples docs - I was hoping that showing the actual example would help people

Comment: So "+ (id)monthArray" is equal "+monthArray"?

Comment: Correct. If you leave out a method return type or parameter type, it's assumed to be type `id`. But please don't use that compiler feature, it's considered bad style. :)